# Apportable SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed Failure

Tags: android, ios, sprite-kit, apportable

I'm working on converting my SpriteKit made, Objective-C app into an Android app through Apportable.  On 'apportable load', I'm running into issues with SKTextureAtlas.

[SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:ATLAS_NAME_CONSTANT] gives back nil when running on Android, which it doesn't do when running on iPhone.

Are there any particular work-arounds to get a texture atlas to work nicely with Apportable, or am I going to be stuck using regular images?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, our SpriteKit is a hacked-together-over-a-weekend implementation. If it's currently working for regular images, I'd recommend keeping it that way. Internally, we're considering how we can better support SpriteKit in the future--look for notes in future SDK releases.

Comment: Is there any documentation of what features of SpriteKit are supported?  When can I expect a release with added SpriteKit features?

Comment: i think that the only good answer is: we don't currently support spritekit, but we hope to soon.